# Error while building Flutter iOS-App with Codemagic

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, codemagic

While building an iOS-App with Codemaigc I get the following error message and the build failed:

```
Building a deployable iOS app requires a selected Development Team with a 
Provisioning Profile. Please ensure that a Development Team is selected by:
  1- Open the Flutter project's Xcode target with
   open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
  2- Select the 'Runner' project in the navigator then the 'Runner' target
 in the project settings
  3- Make sure a 'Development Team' is selected under Signing & Capabilities > Team. 
 You may need to:
     - Log in with your Apple ID in Xcode first
     - Ensure you have a valid unique Bundle ID
     - Register your device with your Apple Developer Account
     - Let Xcode automatically provision a profile for your app
  4- Build or run your project again
```

How can I solve this? I am using Android Studio on Windows and my Android App is already running.

Comment: You need to build iOS apps on a Mac with Xcode. You can't do it on windows

Comment: It could also be a macOs VM

Comment: I am using Codemagic